# get distinct items in a collection if other item is not null

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like this

```
{
Country : 'XYZ'
Books : [
         {"name" : "book1", "url" : "book1url", "auth_email" : "emailid1"},
         {"name" : "book2", "url" : "book2url", "auth_email" : "emailid2"},
         {"name" : "book3", "url" : "book3url", "auth_email" : "emailid3"},
         {"name" : "book4", "url" : "book4url", "auth_email" : "emailid4"}
         ..........................................
       ]
```

}

I want to extract
 `distinct 'Books.name' and corresponding 'Books.email'` 
only if 
`'Books.email' is not = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the easiest way I can come up with the at the moment is to unwind the `Books` array, match only those that have an email value and then form the root documents back up:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$Books'},
    {$match: {'Books.auth_email':{$nin:['',null]}}},
    {$group: {_id:'$Books.name',email:{$first:'$Books.auth_email'}}}
])
```

Though another way which should work as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$Books'},
    {$match: {'Books.auth_email':{$nin:['',null]}}},
    {$group: {_id:'$_id',Country:'$Country',Books:{$addToSet:'$Books'}}}
])
```

I believe that in python you can just do:

```
self.mongo.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$Books"},
    {"$match": {"Books.auth_email":{"$nin":['',null]}}},
    {"$group": {"_id":"$Books.name","email":{"$first":"$Books.auth_email"}}}
])
```

Comment: @Sammayeif their is a way to do it in python using pymongo

Comment: @AnuragSharma I must admit my knowledge of python is a bit limited currently but I think I can add a python edition

Comment: @AnuragSharma I think that might be a python edition, I beleive it is as simple as adding the speech makrs everywhere, but I am unsure

Comment: @SammayeSorry, Your 3rd query results in an syntax error in python

Comment: Their is a problem with the null in the 3rd line. i removed it and it worked

Comment: @AnuragSharma Indeed I just remembered, null is actually `None` in python